# How can I test if a dehydrator is getting to the proper temperature?

Tags: dehydrating

I'm trying to sell an Aroma 5 tray dehydrator and want to make sure it's working correctly. What temperature should it be getting to and how do I test for it?

Answer (score 2):

The [manual for the Aroma 5-tray dehydrator](http://www.aroma-housewares.com/manuals/AFD-615_InstructionManual.pdf) says that the drying temperature is about 150°F (65°C). So all you need to do is find a thermometer that you can fit inside it, turn it on, wait 5-10 minutes for it to heat up, and check the temperature.

You could also simply test it by drying a quick test batch of something; if it gets nicely dehydrated in roughly the expected amount of time, the temperature was probably fine.